# Moving Zeros to the end of an array in java using temporary variables and without using any utils

Tags: java, arrays

I want to move Zeros in an int array to the end.My plan was to make a new array, put the non zero numbers in order into the new array while another loop takes the zeros and put them at the end of the array
P.S i have a int value that counts the number of zeros and the final positions of the zeros would be determined by the length of the array - count++

I have tried storing non zero numbers into a temporary array and putting the zeros at the original positions of the non zero numbers(only applicable to non zero numbers at the end of the array)

```
public class movezeros {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 0, 4, 0, 1, 3, 4 };
        int[] array1 = new int[numbers.length];

        int i;
        int temp = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (numbers[i] != 0) {
                array1[i] = numbers[i];
            }
            if (numbers[i] == 0) {
                count++;
                temp = numbers[i];
                array1[numbers.length - count++] = temp;
            }
            System.out.print(array1[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the system to out put array1 with the zeros moved to the end but the actual output is just all the numbers at their initial positions

Comment: @NicholasK While the task in that question is the same, I believe we can help this asker better by pointing out what’s wrong in his/her code. Which requires regarding it as a new question, not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

This line gives you a new array filled with zeroes:

```
    int[] array1 = new int[numbers.length];
```

When you do

```
            array1[i] = numbers[i];
```

— you are moving the number to *the same index* in the new array. Thereby you are still leaving zeroes between the moved numbers, so the result appears to be the same array.

Instead you need to keep a separate index into `array1` pointing to the next location that you have not yet filled. This is where you will want to put the next non-zero element from `numbers`.

Tip: since the new array is filled with zeroes from the creation, you don’t need to do anything to move the zeroes over.

Tip: Use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));` for printing the entire new array. It’ll give more readable output.

Comment: What do you mean by keeping a separate index into array1?

Comment: An `int` variable just like just like `i` and in addition to it. @Blorglue So you can put something else than `i` inside `array1[i]` when moving a number.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class StackOverflow1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 0, 4, 0, 1, 3, 4 };
    int[] array1 = new int[numbers.length];

    int i;
    int temp;
    int count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if ((numbers[i] != 0)) {
            temp = numbers[count];
            numbers[count] = numbers[i];
            numbers[i] = temp;
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
}
}
```

Output: [1, 2, 4, 5, 4, 1, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: Thanks for contributing. This answer is too much spoon-feeding and to little explanation for my taste. As I see it, you risk solving the asker’s homework assignment for him or her, in the worst case without him or her understanding the solution. Instead I suggest you try to help them learn so they can solve their own assignment.

Comment: @mitesh7172.... i understand what you did there but one of my restrictions is that i cannot import any packages or utils.

Comment: @Blorglue The imported `Arrays` util class is only used for printing, Moving the elements is done without the import.